# Gradle, android java aapt build failing with C errors

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am using Gradle to build an Android application that includes the Facebook library with:

`gradle build --debug`

But I receive this error output:

Failed to run command:

```
aapt package -v -f --no-crunch -I 
/etc/android/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M 
/facebook-android-sdk-3.16/build/intermediates/bundles/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S 
/facebook-android-sdk-3.16/build/intermediates/bundles/release/res -A 
/facebook-android-sdk-3.16/build/intermediates/bundles/release/assets -m -J 
/facebook-android-sdk-3.16/build/generated/source/r/release --custom-package com.facebook.android --non-constant-id -0 apk --output-text-symbols 
/facebook-android-sdk-3.16/build/intermediates/bundles/release

Error Code:
2
Output:

/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �������!8__PAGEZERO__TEXT: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �__stub_helper__TEXT$�: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: $�: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �__cstring__TEXT��: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: �: not found
/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: ��__symbol_stub__TEXT: not found
```

What could be causing such an error?

- The application builds fine locally but fails on the build server.
- The permission of aapt is set to 777
- I am not using any native code

Comment: is that native code? Native code isn't supported with Gradle quite yet with Android Studio without some plugins. You have to use ANT or Maven I think.

Comment: No it is not native code

Comment: I saw cstring and I assumed, my bad.

Comment: guess why studio is still in beta. May have to resort to porting into Eclipse and using ANT.